# asp.net core FileNotFoundException fresh project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-1.1

I just created new asp.net core 1.1 web app, add nuget packages

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

and references to my other projects

```
MySolution.Core
MySolution.Models
MySolution.Utilities
```

If i keep HomeController as it was created, sample site running fine.
But when I add next code into HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyRepository _repository;

    public HomeController(MyRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I getting error on app running:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySolution.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, int cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
```

Models project referencing entity framework package.

How can I fix that error?

Comment: What specific code did you add to your home controller?  Did you replace everything that was there with the code listed above?

Comment: did you do DI of MyRepository in Configuration method?

Comment: please add code of MyRepository class, IMyRepository interface and how you do DI.

Comment: and did you try to compile project?

Comment: @Alex thanks for DI point, I forgot to use ConfigureServices - was really sleepy and tired. Added repository into DI and exception gone. But controller method never called, same with Startup.ConfigureServices and Configure - I put breakpoints inside of those methods and bp never fired.

Comment: but Hope page opened? Did you run in debug mode?

Comment: not Hope but Home

Comment: You know it's weird, but it's just started working fine when I returned today. 

So DI injection was missing, that was root cause.

Answer (score 0):

So it was DI configuration missing.

Use your Startup.cs to configure dependencies